# XSLT string replace as function

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this mods

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modsCollection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:dabar="http://dabar.srce.hr/standards/schema/1.0" xmlns:mads="http://www.loc.gov/mads/v2" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <mods ID="master">
    <relatedItem type="constituent">
      <identifier>777777</identifier>
      <titleInfo type="alternative">
        <title>EXTRA</title>
      </titleInfo>
      <titleInfo lang="hrv">
        <title>PRE/POST</title>
      </titleInfo>
      <identifier type="local">666666</identifier>
      <name type="corporate" displayLabel="jurisdiction" authority="iso3166">
        <namePart>EU</namePart>
      </name>
      <name type="corporate">
        <namePart>EC</namePart>
      </name>
      <name>
        <namePart>H200</namePart>
      </name>
      <name type="personal">
        <role>
          <roleTerm type="text" authority="marcrelator">Project director</roleTerm>
          <roleTerm lang="hrv">Voditelj projekta</roleTerm>
        </role>
        <namePart>Name Surname</namePart>
      </name>
    </relatedItem>
   </mods>
</modsCollection>
```

And I have this transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" exclude-result-prefixes="mods"
                xmlns:mads="http://www.loc.gov/mads/v2"
                xmlns:dabar="http://dabar.srce.hr/standards/schema/1.0"
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                xmlns:srw_dc="info:srw/schema/1/dc-schema"
                xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="//mods:mods[@ID = 'master']/mods:relatedItem">

        <xsl:choose>

            <!-- Projekt -->
            <xsl:when test="@type='constituent' and not(@displayLabel)">

                <xsl:if test="mods:identifier[@type='local' and normalize-space() != '']">
                    <dc:relation>
                        <xsl:text>info:eu-repo/grantAgreement</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:name[@type='corporate' and not(@displayLabel)]/mods:namePart)" />
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:name[not(@type)]/mods:namePart)" />
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:identifier[not(@type)])" />
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:name[@type='corporate' and @displayLabel='jurisdiction']/mods:namePart)" />
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="mods:titleInfo[@lang = 'eng']">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:titleInfo[not(@type='alternative') and @lang='eng']/mods:title)" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:titleInfo[1][not(@type='alternative')]/mods:title)" />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:if test="mods:titleInfo[@type='alternative']/mods:title">
                            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:titleInfo[@type='alternative']/mods:title)" />
                        </xsl:if>
                    </dc:relation>
                </xsl:if>

            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is my result that I'm getting out

```
<oai_dc:dc xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
  <dc:relation>info:eu-repo/grantAgreement/PRE/POST/H200/77777/EU//EXTREMDRON</dc:relation>
</oai_dc:dc>
```

instead of this

info:eu-repo/grantAgreement/**PRE/POST**/H200/76789/EUA//EXTRA

But I **want to get** this:

```
<dc:relation>info:eu-repo/grantAgreement/**PRE%2FPOST**/H200/76789/EU//EXTRa</dc:relation>
```

So I transform mods to dc, and I have an order in which mods elements are put into a dc element. when a mods element value has a '/' inside it I need to recode it to '%2F' (/ -> %2F)

I looked at similar topics and saw that for XSLT-1.0 you need a template `replace-string` for it. And the problem is that I can't find a way to call this template

I tried the following ways:

```
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="replace-string(normalize-space(mods:name[@type='corporate' and not(@displayLabel)]/mods:namePart),'/','%2F')" />
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
```

and

```
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
<xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(mods:titleInfo[not(@type='alternative') and @lang='eng']/mods:title")/>
  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'/'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'%2F'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
```

The first way as using it as a function would be much more user friendly and code readable.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, you could potentially make use of extension function (See http://exslt.org/str/), but generally the `xsl:call-template` approach is the way to go. Your current code snippet for `xsl:call-template` looks correct, although there is a syntax error in your `select` class for the `text` parameter, as you are missing a closing bracket at the end.

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, can you edit your question to include a sample of your XML, which would allow us to reproduce your problem and hopefully offer up a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC - here i added more info on what the transform looks like. in the end all values gathered from mods will have to get rid of /, so the fit nicely in info:eu-repo/grantAgrement///// , thats why im looking for a "one-line call solution"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not replacing a single character with another single character (in which case you could use the `translate` function), one approach you can take to avoid writing out the `xsl:call-template` multiple times, is to have a template matching `text()` where you then do the call in one place.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'/'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'%2F'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, instead of doing of using `xsl:value-of` to output the text (Note, that I adjusted your current expression, as for your given XML, it was actually not outputting anything)

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(mods:titleInfo[not(@type='alternative')][1]/mods:title)" />
```

Replace it with `xsl:apply-templates`

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="mods:titleInfo[not(@type='alternative')][1]/mods:title/text()" />
```

Also note how this means you only have `normalize-space()` in one place now too.

**EDIT**: If you don't want to be so generic, you could make use of the `mode` attribute to avoid all text being changed

SO, the text template looks this this...

```
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="replace">
<xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'/'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'%2F'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

And the `xsl:apply-templates` looks like this...

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="mods:titleInfo[not(@type='alternative')][1]/mods:title/text()" mode="replace" />
```

For text your didn't want updating, simply omit the `mode` attribute`.

Comment: wont this cause problems for other elemnts that might have / in them?
because of confidentiality i only included the mods elemnts that i had the problem of transforming

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to handle the cases where you might not want to do the replace.